# The program for converting ppm to ASCII art does not work properly

Tags: c, rgb, grayscale, ascii-art

I am writing a program for converting a file from PPM format to ASCII art. Every pixel of the input image is converted to greyscale by calculating the average of red green and blue values `((red + green +blue)/3)`.

The upgrade of the basic version is that I calculate the average of RGB in a window of size `n*n`, and convert it to a character which would decrease the size of the image. So if the given number `n` is `3`, the window is of size `3*3`, which means that you sum all nine red, green and blue values and divide it by 3 times `n*n` (`3*3` in this case). When the program counts the greyscale for the first window, it moves to the other one and so on until the end. When there is the end of width, it jumps down by the n number of pixels and reads the next line, etc.

When the greyscale is calculated it is then converted to a character and this character is being written to the output file to form an ASCII art image.

My program does compile, but when I test it, I get the wrong image. One very simple image converted to a blank file, the other should look like a chessboard but it printed a very large image of columns. Both of these images were converted to ASCII art by scanning blocks of pixels 1*1. The third image is very big, so it should be converted by 3*3 blocks, but the output file I got was too big to be opened. in a simple text editor.

Can anyone tell me where I made a mistake?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// convert the calculated greyscale to a character based on brightness
char method_of_conversion(int greyscale){
    if(greyscale >= 230){
        return ' ';
    }else if(greyscale >= 200 && greyscale < 230){
        return '.';
    }else if(greyscale >= 180 && greyscale < 200){
        return '\'';
    }else if(greyscale >= 160 && greyscale < 180){
        return ':';
    }else if(greyscale >= 130 && greyscale < 160){
        return 'o';
    }else if(greyscale >= 100 && greyscale < 130){
        return '&';
    }else if(greyscale >= 70 && greyscale < 100){
        return '8';
    }else if(greyscale >= 50 && greyscale < 70){
        return '#';
    }else if(greyscale < 50){
        return '@';
    }
}

int main(){
    char ppmFile[100];
    char outputFile[100];

    int n;

    scanf("%s", &ppmFile); //read the name of input file
    scanf("%s", &outputFile); //read the name of output file 
    // the size of a window of pixels you have to convert to ascii art character
    scanf("%d", &n); 

    FILE *input = fopen(ppmFile, "rb");
    FILE *output = fopen(outputFile, "w"); 

    int width, height; // max pixel is always 255
    // read the header from the ppm file
    fscanf(input, "P6\n%d %d\n255\n", &width, &height);

    // allocate place for array[width][length][3]
    int a, b;
    int ***array;
    array = malloc(width*sizeof(int **));
    for(a = 0; a < width; a++){
        array[a] = malloc(height*sizeof(int *));
        for(b = 0; b < height; b++){
            array[a][b] = malloc(3*sizeof(int));
        }
    }

    int x, y;
    for (x = 0; x < width; x++){ 
        for(y=0; y < height; y++){
            array[x][y][0] = fgetc(input); //red
            array[x][y][1] = fgetc(input); //green
            array[x][y][2] = fgetc(input); //blue

            int greyscale;
            int i, j;
            // convert blocks of pixels to a character and write it into output file
            for(i = 0; i < width; i+=n){
                for(j=0; j < height; j+=n){
                    // greyscale = (red + green +blue)/3;
                    greyscale = (array[i][j][0] + array[i][j][1] +array[i][j][2])/(3*n*n);
                    char c = method_of_conversion(greyscale);
                    fprintf(output,"%c",c); // write the ASCII art directly in the output file
                }
            }   
        }fprintf(output,"\n"); // dont forget to go into a new line
    }

    free(array);
    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to read the whole file first then scan through it and write your output.  Right now you're writing a lot of output per pixel and indexing into parts of the array that haven't been read yet.

Comment: Consider using an RGB structure instead of a 3rd dimension in your `array`.  Much cleaner to read and you don't need an array here as you aren't looping on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These Lines:

```
       for(i = 0; i < width; i+=n){
            for(j=0; j < height; j+=n){
```

are probably not correct.  If `n = 3`, you read every 3rd pixel across the X and Y of your image instead of a local block.  This will give you a scattered dataset instead of a block.

Or... You place a 2nd set of for loops inside this code that counts from `0` to `n-1` and reads all the pixels to be averaged.  That actually is probably the missing piece here.

```
       for(i = 0; i < width; i+=n){
            for(j=0; j < height; j+=n){

               for(blockx = 0; blockx  < n; blockx++){
                    for(blocky=0; blocky < n; blocky++){
                        // Use current averaging code to gather all numbers, 
                        // being careful of overflow.
```